# AWS Libraries causing NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, android-studio

I am trying to implement AWS Amplify/Cognito libraries for my app, but am getting the following error when launching the application on an emulator running Marshmallow. I followed the [following instructions](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/building-an-android-app-with-aws-amplify-part-1/), but it still isn't working because I am getting the following error:

```
 2021-06-26 11:02:01.160 9787-9815/com.example.sprout E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2
    Process: com.example.sprout, PID: 9787
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity;
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient.getClient(AWSMobileClient.java:2139)
        at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient$19.run(AWSMobileClient.java:2005)
        at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.internal.InternalCallback.await(InternalCallback.java:115)
        at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient.showSignIn(AWSMobileClient.java:1957)
        at com.example.sprout.AuthenticationActivity.showSignIn(AuthenticationActivity.kt:42)
        at com.example.sprout.AuthenticationActivity.access$showSignIn(AuthenticationActivity.kt:12)
        at com.example.sprout.AuthenticationActivity$onCreate$1.onResult(AuthenticationActivity.kt:26)
        at com.example.sprout.AuthenticationActivity$onCreate$1.onResult(AuthenticationActivity.kt:18)
        at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.internal.InternalCallback.call(InternalCallback.java:75)
        at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.internal.InternalCallback.onResult(InternalCallback.java:62)
        at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient$2.run(AWSMobileClient.java:424)
        at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.internal.InternalCallback$1.run(InternalCallback.java:101)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~orMxE1QpBfs6NjTHCuQmbw==/com.example.sprout-oiakh9w-JZy8uH5nAXFAHw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~orMxE1QpBfs6NjTHCuQmbw==/com.example.sprout-oiakh9w-JZy8uH5nAXFAHw==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system_ext/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient.getClient(AWSMobileClient.java:2139) 
        at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient$19.run(AWSMobileClient.java:2005) 
        at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.internal.InternalCallback.await(InternalCallback.java:115) 
        at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient.showSignIn(AWSMobileClient.java:1957) 
        at com.example.sprout.AuthenticationActivity.showSignIn(AuthenticationActivity.kt:42) 
        at com.example.sprout.AuthenticationActivity.access$showSignIn(AuthenticationActivity.kt:12) 
        at com.example.sprout.AuthenticationActivity$onCreate$1.onResult(AuthenticationActivity.kt:26) 
        at com.example.sprout.AuthenticationActivity$onCreate$1.onResult(AuthenticationActivity.kt:18) 
        at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.internal.InternalCallback.call(InternalCallback.java:75) 
        at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.internal.InternalCallback.onResult(InternalCallback.java:62) 
        at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient$2.run(AWSMobileClient.java:424) 
        at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.internal.InternalCallback$1.run(InternalCallback.java:101) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Here is my project gradle:

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.10"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven{
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-appsync-gradle-plugin:3.1.4'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
        maven{
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And here is my app gradle:

```
 plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'com.amazonaws.appsync'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sprout"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-appsync:2.6.+'
    implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.2.0'
    implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.1.1'
    // Mobile Client for initializing the SDK
    implementation('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.8.+@aar') { transitive = true }
    // Cognito UserPools for SignIn
    implementation('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-auth-userpools:2.8.+@aar') { transitive = true }
    // Sign in UI Library
    implementation('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-auth-ui:2.8.+@aar') { transitive = true }
    implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

Any clue what I might be doing wrong? Thanks in advance!